# AbstractMethodError thrown by org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init> when upgrading from Spring Boot 1.3 to 1.4 RC1

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I have a pretty simple Spring Boot 1.3 app and I'm trying to upgrade to 1.4 RC1. There's nothing that not pretty much out of the box configuration. When I try and start the app or run tests, I get the following:

```
12:06:27.237 [QUIET] [system.out] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
12:06:27.237 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.237 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.237 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.237 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.237 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.238 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.238 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.238 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.238 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.238 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.238 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RC1.jar:1.4.0.RC1]
12:06:27.238 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RC1.jar:1.4.0.RC1]
12:06:27.238 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RC1.jar:1.4.0.RC1]
12:06:27.238 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RC1.jar:1.4.0.RC1]
12:06:27.238 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RC1.jar:1.4.0.RC1]
12:06:27.238 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RC1.jar:1.4.0.RC1]
12:06:27.239 [QUIET] [system.out]   at com.hightouchinc.notifications.NotificationsApplication.main(NotificationsApplication.java:17) [main/:na]
12:06:27.239 [QUIET] [system.out] Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
12:06:27.239 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
12:06:27.239 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
12:06:27.239 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
12:06:27.239 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.239 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) ~[spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.239 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.239 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.239 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.239 [QUIET] [system.out]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
12:06:27.240 [QUIET] [system.out]   ... 16 common frames omitted
```

My entry point class looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NotificationsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NotificationsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Database config looks like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/notifications
    username: ----
    password: ----
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    generate-ddl: true
```

I've read through all the changelogs for the 1.4 milestones and RC1 and I can't find anything that suggests something I have has changed to cause it not to start.

Dependencies from build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-tx')
    compile('javax.el:javax.el-api:3.0.0')
    compile('com.google.guava:guava:19.0')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hibernate5:2.8.1')
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.7.5")
    compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4')
    compile('org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:4.0.0.GA')
    compile('com.h2database:h2')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1208')
    testCompile('junit:junit')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path')
}
```

Comment: Do you have anything else that's Hibernate-related on the classpath? The line that's failing is attempting to call `integrate` on a `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`, the signature of which has changed in 5.0.

Comment: I've updated the question with my build.gradle dependencies.

Comment: I have had issues with spring boot and guava, have you looked at the dependency tree and see if there is more than one version of guava on the classpath

Comment: Only think listed when I check the tree is `com.google.guava:guava:19.0`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that the problem is this dependency:

```
compile('org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:4.0.0.GA')
```

It contains 3 classes that implement `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`:

- `UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator`
- `UserTypeJodaMoneyHibernateIntegrator`
- `UserTypeLegacyJdkMoneyHibernateIntegrator`

The 5.0.0.GA release of Jadira [contains a change](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html#a5.0.0.GA) that "Fixed Integrator behaviour under Hibernate 5" so it looks like upgrading will fix the problem:

```
compile('org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:5.0.0.GA')
```

Comment: That was it! Good catch. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: The interesting thing is that the newer version 6.0.1.GA breaks Integrator behaviour again (at least in my configuration). So I had to stick with 5.0.0.GA

Comment: @naXa and 7.00.CR1 too.